# In Command Prompt, chkdsk won't run at all

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, chkdsk

I am unable to boot into Windows 8 after restarting during when some mysterious process was using 50% Disk Activity. So, the first thing I'm trying is `chkdsk`, but it doesn't run at all. It simply says `The type of the file system is NTFS.` and then it freezes.

If `chkdsk` does not run, then what does that indicate? Is all my data completely lost? I AM able to use Command Prompt to browse around my directories and use `type` to read text files, so I assume that at least some documents are salvageable?

Comment: Try running `chkdsk` from a Windows installation disk instead of the Recovery environment on your HDD.

Comment: I tried that already. Both from the hard drive and from the Windows 8 DVD. Same problem for both, unfortunately.

Comment: @Moses No.  You either run chkdsk from the recovery console, or from within windows. there isn't a third type of chkdsk. the only difference between whether it's from hdd or from cd, is whether or not you need a restart which you would if it's active.

Comment: maybe a safe move would be to try to make an image of the partition.  Second to that, since chkdsk doesn't work, you could see if the hdd manufacturer has a tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `chkdsk` a few times, it finally ran. When it ran, it finished after about 30 hours. Turns out the hard drive had a lot of bad sectors, so I recovered them with [HDD Regenerator](http://www.dposoft.net/) then I used [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/trueimage/) to clone my internal drive to an external one before I lost everything for good.